# Como receber dados de um formulário através do atributo class do HTML?

Tags: php, css

Sei que é possível "chamar" o name de um formulário em um arquivo php. Mas em um arquivo php, é possível "chamar" uma class feita em um formulário  para obter o mesmo efeito de "chamar" o name, ou seja, como enviar dados de um formulário para um arquivo php atravez de uma class  ?

Especificando, para enviar atravez do name utilizo o seguinte código php:

```
$variável = $_POST['name'];
```

Mas como faço se ao em vez de name for uma class ?

OBS 1; Já tentei apenas substituir o name pela class, mas não funcionou.
OBS 2; Não possuo acesso ao arquivo do formulário, sendo assim, não posso apenas inserir um name para usar o código citado anteriormente.

### Formulário:

```
<table>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Senha</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="senha">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="submit" class="botao-login" value="Login">
    </form>
</table>
```

Observe que no botão de login não possui o name.Estou tentando fazer uma função em php para autenticação de login,cujo esta função é a "isset".A saber, ao pressionar o botão o seguinte código php é executado:

### Código php

```
<?php
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha   = $_POST['senha'];
$botao   = $_POST['é aqui que costumo por o name do botão'];

if (isset($botao)) {
    if ($usuario == "" or $senha == "") {
        $mensagem = "Campo em branco";
    } elseif ($usuario != $_COOKIE['usuario'] or $senha != $_COOKIE['senha']) {
        $mensagem = "Usuáriorio ou senha inválido";
    } elseif ($usuario == $_COOKIE['usuario'] && $senha == $_COOKIE['senha'] && $_COOKIE['tipo_conta'] == "administrador") {
        header("Location:php/administrador.php");
    } elseif ($usuario == $_COOKIE['usuario'] && $senha == $_COOKIE['senha'] && $_COOKIE['tipo_conta'] == "registrado") {
        header("Location:php/registrado.php");
    } elseif ($usuario == $_COOKIE['usuario'] && $senha == $_COOKIE['senha'] && $_COOKIE['tipo_conta'] == "indefinido") {
        header("Location:php/indefinido.php");
    }
}
?>
```

O código php não está na mesma página cujo encontra-se o formulário.Como dito anteriormente, o código php é executado ao pressionar o botão, porem para que o código funcione, é viável que ele possua um name para que eu possa utilizar o sequinte código `$variável = $_POST['name'];`.Existe algum código php para que a função "isset" funcione sem a necessidade de um name ?

Comment: Pra que verificar se aquele botão foi clicado? Esse mesmo php recebe dados de outros formulários?

Comment: complicado entender, mas não é possível que o PHP enxergue o atributo class de uma tag HTML dessa forma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os seletores *class* e *id*  são seletores de atributo, e são normalmente utilizados para identificar um elemento *html*. Em casos comuns, vêm-se estes elementos a ser utilizados para identificar elementos especificos a serem estilizados utilizando folhas de estilo *(CSS)*, sendo que o atributo *id*, é utilizando para identificar elementos com propriedades únicas, e o atributo *class* para vários elementos com mesmas propriedades.

O atributo *name* é usado para referenciar um elemento em javascript, ou uma referência para o formulário, depois de ele ter sido submetido. Basicamente funcionam como bandeiras durante o envio de um formulário. Por exemplo, se se tiver vários *radio* com diferentes *id*, e neles colocarmos o mesmo atributo *name*, durante a submissão do formulário, apenas o valor o botão *radio* selecionado sera passado. [«1»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html)

No final, chega-se a conclusão de que, receber dados de formulários através de atributos *class* ou *id* **não é possível**.

Pode-se tentar até dar algumas voltas, utilizando *Ajax*, e lendo os valores dos campos identificados com o atributo *id* em vez de *name*, mas no final, acaba-se por definir um método para requisição, de modo a haver troca de dados digitados no formulário, com o script no servidor, lembrando que as requisições para o servidor só aceitam identificadores do tipo *name*.

**Exemplo:**

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="nome" value="Meu nome com name"/>
<input type="text" id="nome" value="Meu nome com id"/>  
<button onclick="mostra()">Mostrar</button>
</form>
<script>
function mostra(){
    var nome = document.getElementsByName('nome')[0].value;
    var id = document.getElementById('nome').value;

    alert('atributo name: ' + nome + '\n  atributo id: ' + id);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```